# changing the disabled font color

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, disabled-control

THis is a list table, and one list is disabled. As you guys know, the font color is a gray when it's disabled. I am using IE9, and I want to change the font color. Does anyone know how to change the disabled font color???

here is my code:

```
<table id="list" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr disabled bgcolor =#EAEAEA  style="color:#ea0000;">
<td>name</td>
<td>email</td>
</tr>
<tr class="nameMail" onclick='op()'>
<td id="a">&nbsp</td>
<td id="b">&nbsp</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `disabled` attribute in your `<tr>` element? That's certainly not valid in HTML 4.01, and I don't believe it's valid in HTML 5 either.

Comment: because the first <tr> is a list title, so I do not want it's selected when I hit the <tr>. op() is for the option "selected"

Comment: @Albright Table row selection has to be handled in Javascript anyway. Just make it skip title rows, marked using something semantic like `class="header"`.

Comment: Why are you using outdated attributes for style, borders, etc?

Comment: @millimoose - html provides a built-in method of semantically marking heading rows: the `<thead>` element...

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, that's the better choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is invalid.

You would do something like this:

```
 input[type="text"]:disabled
 {
    color:#ea0000;
 }
```

Also, 'disabled' selector is supposed to be used mostly with form elements and controls.

If you want you can use a button within the tds like so:

```
  <table id="list" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr bgcolor="#EAEAEA"  style="color:#ea0000;">
        <td><button disabled>name</button></td>
       <td><button disabled>email</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nameMail" onclick='op()'>
        <td id="a">&nbsp</td>
        <td id="b">&nbsp</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

You would also, need to update the css like so to get rid of the button border.

```
  button{
   border:0;
   color:#ea0000;
   }

  button:disabled
  {
   color:#000;
  }
```

Comment: Do I need to use input?? That's just a list table. it's not to be editable.

Comment: Well, you could use a button for your purpose instead.